# How to set dynamic width for the ul by postitioning it properly?

Tags: magento-1.9, submenu

In magento1.9.2.4 I want to display the menu like this:
[image]

My styles for this menu is below:

```
    .nav-primary {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -85px;
}
.nav-primary li.level0, .nav-primary a.level0 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-primary li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 > a {
    color: #70583a;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.nav-primary a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.nav-primary li.level1 {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eae4da;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 li.parent > a {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level1 ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 li.parent > a {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0 {
    width: 655px;
    max-width: 740px;
}
.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0, .nav-primary li.level0 li.sub-menu-active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here I have fixed the width like

```
.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0{
    width:655px;                                         
    max-width:740px;                

}
```

When I remove the width for this element the menu is like this:

[image]

I want to have dynamic width which will adjust according to the menu added instead of fixing it manually.I think there is a problem with positioning. Help me to resolve this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. It is not positioning issue. I just gave the below jquery in `topmenu.phtml` :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.level0 ul.level0').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).width(parseInt(jQuery(this).children().length * 185, 10) + 'px');
    });
});
</script>
```

Now the width is set dynamically.

This answer may help someone like me.